# Como inicializar dinamicamente um select2 no angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select, bootstrap, jquery-select2

Olá pessoal estou usando o plugin do select2 em meu projeto. Estou precisando criar vários selects2 dinamicamente, pelo angular. Tenho um vetor de objetos(com id, nome) e preciso a partir de um evento, em uma função gerar um select para de cada objeto, podendo diferenciar a chave pelo id. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Função:

```
angular.forEach(camada.filtros, function (filtro)
        {
            var s = "select_multiple"+filtro.id;
            $('#myModalBody').on('DOMNodeInserted', s, function () {
                $(this).select2();
            });
```

HTML:

```
<div class="modal-body" id="myModalBody" ng-repeat="filtro in filtros"> 
                        <select class="select_multiple" id="select_multiple{{filtro.id}}" multiple="multiple" style="width: 400px;" ng-model="filtrosCamadasSelecionadas" >
                            <option>asdasd</option>
                            <option>vvvvv</option>
                            <option>bbbbbb</option>
                            <option>aaaaaaa</option>
                            <option>xxxxxx</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
```

O código a cima não está funcionando, é apenas uma parte para terem uma ideia. Tentei usar isso com ideia em alguns links que vi, porém não consegui nada ainda.

Comment: Você pode colocar um exemplo do que está no objeto filtro?